# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Structure of my database:

[image]
a,b,s are my building names; 1,1,2 are floor numbers; 1,1,3 are flat numbers and ra111,rb111,rs231 are my user ids.
I am trying to implement a list view showing building names and then clicking on any building name the list view shows corresponding floor numbers and clicking on floor number it should show corresponding flat numbers.

```
 DatabaseReference ref,ref2,ref3;
 ListView listBuildings,listFloors,listFlats;
 ArrayAdapter<String>adapterBuildings,adapterFloors,adapterFlats;
 String[] arrayOfBuildings,arrayOfFloors,arrayOfFlats;

ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("structure");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                HashMap<String,Object>structure = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Set<String>buildings = structure.keySet();
                arrayOfBuildings = buildings.toArray(new String[0]);
                adapterBuildings = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfBuildings);
                listBuildings.setAdapter(adapterBuildings);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


listBuildings.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textViewList.setText("Select the floor number");
                String building = arrayOfBuildings[position];
                Log.i("building",building);
                ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("structure").child(building);
                listBuildings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                listFloors.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Log.i("datasnapshot",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        Log.i("key",dataSnapshot.getKey());

                        HashMap<String,Object>structure = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        Set<String>floors = structure.keySet();
                        arrayOfFloors = floors.toArray(new String[0]);
                        adapterFloors = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfFloors);
                        listFloors.setAdapter(adapterFloors);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

 listFloors.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textViewList.setText("Select the flat number and press submit");
                String floor = arrayOfFloors[position];
                Log.i("floor",floor);
                ref3 = ref2.child(floor);
                listFlats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                listFloors.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ref3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Log.i("datasnapshot",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        HashMap<String,Object>f = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        Set<String>flats = f.keySet();
                        arrayOfFlats = flats.toArray(new String[0]);
                        adapterFlats = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayOfFlats);
                        listFlats.setAdapter(adapterFlats);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

But when I try to retrieve data building wise:
it shows me 
a
b
s
On clicking on s, it shows me correct floor:
2
But if I click on building a or building b:
It gives me error: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap. If I log the datasnapShot values, it shows me: [null, [null, {rb111=default}]].
I am not understanding why this is happening and why it works correctly for building 's'.

Please help!
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Is it a fixed schema or you can also change it?

Comment: I can change it but my other activities are based on this schema so it would be a toughie.

Answer (score 1):

> it shows me: [null, [null, {rb111=default}]]. I am not understanding why this is happening

Reason to show `null` here is your firebase data tree`s some children are numbers. If you use numbers as keys in firebase db it consider as a array.

If you only use `1` as kay name that means it is second element of a array. Firebase thinks first element of array is undefined. So that is null. In `[null, [null, {rb111=default}]].`, `0` element is undefined but `1` is defined that is `[null, {rb111=default}]`. In this `0` element is undefined but `1` is defined that is `{rb111=default}`

I think now you understood why null object in your data object

Comment: Oh yes thanks! So will I get the HashMap if I change the datatype of the keys?

Comment: I can't guarantee about it. Just try and if there is a problem, update the question