# Firebase Realtime database automaticlly add an extra null when put data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to put data with integers as key to the realtime database, like this:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4}'  ${firebase}'/test.json?print=pretty'
```

The database automatically add an `null`!
[image]

However, if I use data with 0 as start:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"0":0,"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4}'  ${firebase}'/test.json?print=pretty'
```

[image]
No more extra `null`.
Why does it happen?
And what I want is no more extra `null` with no "0" as key.

Hope for your answer :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Firebase's array coercion. When it sees a node whose child keys are mostly sequential numbers, it assumes you're trying to store an array. It makes sure that the data is actually an array, by adding placeholders for the missing elements.

To prevent Firebase from doing this, ensure that the keys are always strings that can't be converted to numbers, for example by prefixing them: `curl -X PUT -d '{"key_1": 1, "key_2": 2, "key_3": 3, "key_4": 4}'`.

Also see:

- [After 7th child Realtime database "convert" to json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60046070/after-7th-child-realtime-database-convert-to-json-array/60046319#60046319)
- [java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap Firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190778/java-util-arraylist-cannot-be-cast-to-java-util-hashmap-firebase-android/58192206#58192206)